# Parsing tag’s properties from HTML with php

Tags: php, html, parsing, beautifulsoup

There are 365 codes that is

```
<sometag class=“day” date=“yyyy-mm-dd” count=“some Int”></sometag>
```

I have to parse date and count with php, beautiful soup or any parsing library which can be use with php and make JSON String

How can I parse? Every tags have same class name that is “day”

I will be waiting for more answers for more wide info. Thank you.

Comment: PHP's [simplexml](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) is enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agree with @Scuzzy. SimpleXML would be the easiest and cleanest way way for this very specific example. Problem with SimpleXML, I have found it to be very slow if you are parsing larger documents.

There's also this library for parsing html which I think you will find very useful if you're screen scraping with php which it looks like you are doing.

http://www.schrenk.com/nostarch/webbots/DSP_download.php

Comment: It will be very helpfull for me and everyone.

Comment: @ChrisYunbinChang, you've received answers for all your questions on SO, but you've accepted none. Why? Please read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)